# How to use setOnClickListener in RecyclerView to move to the next activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am creating a task management android app for my finals. The problem I have is that when I add a task(sub-task) in Category A (task), I am able to see the task in another category and virce verca. I want a task to only be available under the category it was created. When I click the category, I want to be directed to the tasks that I have created under that category. Pls help, I am desperate!! Below is the code.

```
`
```

class ModelClass {

```
var id: String = ""
var category: String = ""
var dateCreated: Long = 0
var uid: String = ""

constructor(id: String, category: String, dateCreated: Long, uid: String) {
    this.id = id
    this.category = category
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated
    this.uid = uid
}
```

}

```
`

`
```

class AdapterCategory: RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterCategory.HolderCategory>, Filterable {

```
private val context: Context
public var categoryArrayList: ArrayList<ModelClass>
private var filterList: ArrayList<ModelClass>

private var filter: FilterCategory? = null

private lateinit var binding: RowLayoutBinding

constructor(context: Context, categoryArrayList: ArrayList<ModelClass>) {
    this.context = context
    this.categoryArrayList = categoryArrayList
    this.filterList = categoryArrayList
}


inner class HolderCategory(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    
    var categoryTv: TextView = binding.categoryTV
    var deleteButton: ImageButton = binding.deleteButton

}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HolderCategory {
    
    binding = RowLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
    
    return HolderCategory(binding.root)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HolderCategory, position: Int) {
    
    val model = categoryArrayList[position]
    val id = model.id
    val category = model.category
    val uid = model.uid
    val timestamp = model.dateCreated

    holder.categoryTv.text = category

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener{
    
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setTitle("Delete").setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this category?")
            .setPositiveButton("Confirm"){a, d->
                Toast.makeText(context, "Deleting category...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                deleteCategory(model, holder)
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel"){a, d->
                a.dismiss()
            }
            .show()
    }

    //handle click, start task activity
    holder.categoryTv.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(context, NewTaskActivity::class.java)
        //intent.putExtra("categoryID",categoryArrayList[position].id)
        intent.putExtra("categoryTitle", categoryArrayList[position].category)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}


private fun deleteCategory(model: ModelClass, holder: HolderCategory) {
    // get id of the category to delete
    val id = model.id

    //Firebase db > categories > category id
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categories")
    ref.child(id)
        .removeValue()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
        .addOnFailureListener{e->
            Toast.makeText(context, "${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return categoryArrayList.size // number of items in the list
}

override fun getFilter(): Filter {
    if(filter == null){
        filter = FilterCategory(filterList, this)
    }
    return filter as FilterCategory
}
```

}

```
`

`
```

class CreateCategory : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityCreateCategoryBinding
private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
private lateinit var progressDialog: ProgressDialog

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityCreateCategoryBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this)
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait")
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)

    binding.backButton.setOnClickListener{
        onBackPressed()
    }

    binding.createListButton.setOnClickListener{
        validateDate()

    }
}

private var categoryList = ""

private fun validateDate() {

    // get data
    categoryList = binding.createTask.text.toString().trim()

    if(categoryList.isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Create category", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else{
        addCategory()
    }
}

private fun addCategory() {
    progressDialog.show()

    val dateCreated =System.currentTimeMillis()

    // setup data to add in firebase db
    val hashMap = HashMap<String, Any>()
    hashMap["id"] = "$dateCreated"
    hashMap["category"] = categoryList
    hashMap["created"] = dateCreated
    hashMap["uid"] = "${(firebaseAuth.uid)}"

    // add to database : Database Root > Categories > categoryId
    val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categories")
    ref.child("$dateCreated").setValue(hashMap).addOnSuccessListener {
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(this, "Created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        if (categoryList.isNotEmpty()){
            var categoryTitle = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.categoryTitle)
            categoryTitle.text = categoryList
            startActivity(Intent(this, Categories::class.java))
        }else{
            categoryList = "Untitled category"
        }
    }.addOnFailureListener{ e->
        progressDialog.dismiss()
        Toast.makeText(this, "${e.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

}

```
`

`
```

class Categories : AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityCategoriesBinding

private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

//arrayList to hold categories
private lateinit var categoryArrayList: ArrayList<ModelClass>

// adapter
private lateinit var adapterCategory: AdapterCategory

private var categoryID = ""
private var categoryTitle = ""


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityCategoriesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    //init firebaseAuth
    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    loadCategories()

    //search
    binding.searchBar.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher{
        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

        }

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            // called as and when user types anything
            try{
                adapterCategory.filter.filter(s)
            }catch (e:Exception){

            }
        }

        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

        }

    })

}


private fun loadCategories() {
    //init arrayList
    categoryArrayList = ArrayList()

    // get all categories from firebase database, Firebase DB > Categories
    var ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Categories")
    ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            // clear list before starting adding data to it
            categoryArrayList.clear()
            for (ds in snapshot.children) {
                // get data as a model
                val model = ds.getValue(ModelClass::class.java)

                //add to arrayList
                categoryArrayList.add(model!!)
            }

            //setup adapter
            adapterCategory = AdapterCategory(this@Categories, categoryArrayList)

            // set adapter to recyclerview
            categoriesRV.adapter = adapterCategory
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }
    })

}
```

}

```
`
```

Comment: It's because you are not adding sub-task, you are adding new task for every single time. There is no field to determine whether it's a task or subtask. Add `var subCategory: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()` to your ModelClass. And use it when you want to add subCategory to a specific category. And when you click on some category in recyclerView, in next page get that category's subcategories and show them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It's a matter of reading the data or a matter of writing the data? Please respond using @AlexMamo